# Parsing a list of string by the last occurring space python

Tags: python, pandas, list, split

I have a list of strings that contain spaces that I need to parse by the last or second to last space (dateTime).  I have tried split() on the main string but the problem is that there are a lot of spaces included for description of data, so instead I deferred to using split(/n) . See below for sample list.

```
['Origin Time       2016/04/16 01:25:00',
 'Lat.              32.753',
 'Long.             130.762',
 'Depth. (km)       12',
 'Mag.              7.3',
 'Station Code      AIC001',
 'Station Lat.      35.2976',
 'Station Long.     136.7500',
 'Station Height(m) 6',
 'Record Time       2016/04/16 01:28:06',
 'Sampling Freq(Hz) 100Hz',
 'Duration Time(s)  120',
 'Dir.              N-S',
 'Scale Factor      7845(gal)/8223790',
 'Max. Acc. (gal)   2.327',
 'Last Correction   2016/04/16 01:28:08'
```

I'm not sure the the best angle is to split  the first and last elements of this list, I would like to separate them so that I can create a pandas Dataframe from it.

Comment: You can try just splitting the strings on the *index* where the division is, since splitting by the rightmost space is not a valid rule for this dataset. The index where the value begins is always the same in your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks a lot like a fixed-width format file, not one formatted using a delimiter.  If your *pre-split* string is in `original`, using [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) with the default 'guess the columns' inference engine will actually work on your sample:

```
import io, pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(original), header=None)
```

But I think it's safer -- or at least more explicit -- to specify what the column widths are directly, whether via `widths` or `colspecs`.

```
In [55]: pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(original), header=None, widths=[17, 100])
Out[55]: 
                    0                    1
0         Origin Time  2016/04/16 01:25:00
1                Lat.               32.753
2               Long.              130.762
3         Depth. (km)                   12
4                Mag.                  7.3
5        Station Code               AIC001
6        Station Lat.              35.2976
7       Station Long.             136.7500
8   Station Height(m)                    6
9         Record Time  2016/04/16 01:28:06
10  Sampling Freq(Hz)                100Hz
11   Duration Time(s)                  120
12               Dir.                  N-S
13       Scale Factor    7845(gal)/8223790
14    Max. Acc. (gal)                2.327
15    Last Correction  2016/04/16 01:28:08
```

Of course, if your file is inconsistently formatted, you might not be so lucky and have to include some workarounds.

FWIW, this is just a glorified version of

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[row[:17].strip(), row[17:].strip()] for row in original.splitlines()])
```

in this case.

Comment: Agh thank you! `df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(original), header=None)` did the trick, The only drawback is that I will be including this method in a loop to iterate over 500+ files.  Do you think there is a better way to do this without resorting to pandas ?

Comment: @Arosa822: er, you said in your question that you were creating pandas DataFrames, so no, I don't think you can avoid resorting to pandas. ;-)  But if you want to make a correctly-split list of lists without using pandas, just use the listcomp I passed _to_ the DataFrame constructor in my last paragraph.  That's pure Python.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  Sorry for the misleading description, this is but a subroutine for a method that will eventually extract the data and append to a DataFrame.